# Multiple Projects - @ComponentScan is not working correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with base

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.abc.xyz.pqr" })
public class IhubApplication {}
```

and library folder where I am loading multiple projects having different packages scanned using

*Project 1:*

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pqr.abc")
public class CustomConfig {

}
```

*Project 2:*

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.xyx"})
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {}
```

**Problem:** On running `IhubApplication`, only one is loading from lib, i.e, `com.abc.xyx`. Project with component scan `com.pqr.abc` is being ignored.

Comment: Try add `@ComponentScan` over `IHubApplication.class`

Comment: CustomConfig was generated through SDK with same class and same package was causing issue. Thank you.